# is std::chrono::duration default initialized to 0

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

Is the d value below initialized (to 0 presumably) or uninitialized (unsafe to read)?

```
std::chrono::system_clock::duration d;
```

[Documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration) says default constructor is defaulted.

std library code below seems to suggest it is uninitialized as ultimately int64_t is a scalar, and scalar's default initialization is no initialization.

Is my understanding correct? It surprised me sightly as `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` is initialized to 0.

```
    struct system_clock
    {
      typedef chrono::nanoseconds                   duration;
...
    /// nanoseconds
    typedef duration<int64_t, nano>         nanoseconds;

...
    template<typename _Rep, typename _Period>
      struct duration
      {
    typedef _Rep                        rep;
    typedef _Period                     period;

...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://eel.is/c++draft/time.duration#2

> `Rep` shall be an arithmetic type or a class emulating an arithmetic type.

http://eel.is/c++draft/time.duration#1

> `constexpr duration() = default;`

Together these say that `duration` is *default-initialized* as `Rep` is *default-initialized*

http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#7

> To *default-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - If `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type ([class]), constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are
>     enumerated ([over.match.ctor]), and the best one for the initializer
>     () is chosen through overload resolution ([over.match]). The
>     constructor thus selected is called, with an empty argument list, to
>     initialize the object. (7.2)
> - If `T` is an array type, each element is default-initialized.
> - Otherwise, no initialization is performed.

Thus:

```
seconds s;  // no initialization.
```

However, this:

```
seconds s{};  // zero-initialize
```

does *value initialization*, which for scalars is *zero-initialization*.

http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#list-3.11

> Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.

http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#8

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type ([class]), then ...
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#6

> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> - if T is a scalar type, the object is initialized to the value obtained by converting the integer literal 0 (zero) to T;90

So `duration` clients have their choice of either uninitialized or zero-initialized, with the std-supplied `duration`s which are guaranteed to have a signed integral `Rep`.  If you use a custom duration with a class type `Rep`, then it will be *default-initialized* by whatever definition *that* `Rep` follows.

Comment: But std::chrono::seconds is a class-type. You omitted text for what happens for the first bullet, which seems to be relevant :( I researched, and zero value initialization for chrono::seconds appears to require zero initialization for 'second'. But does that imply zero initialization of the Rep object? For that to work, the Rep object needs to be a non-static data member. Is this specified explicitly? The library spec says"An implementation may use any technique that provides equivalent observable behavior." for an "exposition only" member. So this doesn't seem to be guaranteed?

Comment: The words you quote prove my argument.  If the implementation has observable behavior other than that specified by the exposition-only data member, then it is not conforming.  The vendor must support the observable behavior of explicitly defaulted default constructor with a `Rep` data member.  The vendor might vary the implementation by say, spelling the data member name something other than `rep_`.

Comment: thanks, I misunderstood what "equivalet observable behavior" means. I thought it means behavior according to all non-"exposition only" rules. Now it's clear to me. In the end, chrono::seconds behaves like a primitive arithmetic type, which is very useful.

Comment: Hmm, this means we should not pass `std::chrono::duration`s by value?

Comment: If you also follow a guideline of not passing `int` by value.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of a `duration` is not specified in the standard, only the interface it must supply.  The default constructor does not explicitly state that the internal state will have any particular value, so you cannot assume that a default constructed duration will be zero initialized.  A particular implementation may do so, and it may be zero initialized for some types used for `_Rep` but not for others.

The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_point) for `time_point` explicitly gives a state for a default constructed time_point, which is why that object is zero initialized.